# Как модифицировать пользовательское поле peewe после сохранения

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

Для примера, у меня есть модель:

```py
class ExampleModel(Base):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    image = ImageField(size=(200, 200))

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'example'
```

ImageField - это мое пользовательское поле:

```py
class ImageField(TextField):
    thumb_size: Tuple[int, int] = None

    def __init__(self, size: Tuple[int, int] = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.thumb_size = size

    def db_value(self, value):
        # ... логика сохранения картинки

        return json.dumps({
            'original': original_path,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail_path
        })

    def python_value(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)
```

Когда я создаю запись, все хорошо (`body.image` имеет тип `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile`):

```py
example: ExampleModel = dict_to_model(ExampleModel, body)
example.save()
```

Но, после сохранения поле `example.image` по прежнему имеет тип `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile`. По моим ожиданиям поле `example.image` должно иметь формат, аналогичный тому, что возвращает метод `python_value()`.

Могу ли я как-то без подачи лишнего запроса `select()` сэмулировать это поведение и получить корректный формат поля `technology.image`?